# Can't access knockout observable inside confirmation method

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, razor, knockout.js

I have a bootstrap confirmation that I display to the user. Once the confirmation is clicked I'd like to access the observable array (this.parameters() )that is within the same class under onCancel method. Tried several method but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
export class ViewModel {
    
    public parameters: KnockoutObservableArray<Parameter>

    constructor() {

        this.parameters = ko.observableArray(new Array<Parameter>());

        $('div.panel-footer button[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
            placement: 'top',
            href: '#',
            title: 'Add Parameter',
            btnOkLabel: 'Save & Resend Email',
            btnOkIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-envelope',
            btnOkClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary',
            btnCancelLabel: 'Save',
            btnCancelIcon: '',
            btnCancelClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary',
            onCancel: (e, target) => {
                this.parameters();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example but I must regretfully inform your that the example does what you want to achieve, so the problem must be somewhere outside of this scope.

Originally I thought it was a `this` context binding bug but with the arrow pointer you should be fine, as you can see in my example on the `confirm` function. But just to be sure, try to implement your `onCancel` function as I have, by binding your function context manually. maybe it'll work then and you can access your class context this way.

```js
class ViewModel {
  constructor() {

    this.confirm = ko.observable(0);
    this.cancel = ko.observable(0);

    $('#foobar').confirmation({
      onConfirm: () => {
        this.confirm(this.confirm() + 1);
      },
      onCancel: (function () {
        this.cancel(this.cancel() + 1);
      }).bind(this)
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-2rNj2KJ+D8s1ceNasTIex6z4HWyOnEYLVC3FigGOmyQCZc2eBXKgOxQmo3oKLHyfcj53uz4QMsRCWNbLd32Q1g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-confirmation2/dist/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>
<p><button id="foobar">click here</button></p>
<p>confirm: <span data-bind="text: $root.confirm"></span></p>
<p>cancel: <span data-bind="text: $root.cancel"></span></p>
```